# adding content to div dynamically

Tags: jquery

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#firstImg").click(function(){
        $('<p>Shankar Dayal Sharma was the ninth President of India</p>').appendTo('#content');
        $('#content').show();
    });
    $("#secondImg").click(function(){
        $('<p>.Kocheril Raman Narayanan was the tenth President of India.<p>').appendTo('#content');
        $('#content').show();
    });
    $("#thirdImg").click(function(){
        $('<p>.Avul Pakir Jainulabdeen "A. P. J." Abdul Kalam  was the 11th President of India from 2002 to 2007.</p>').appendTo('#content');
        $('#content').show();
    });
    $("#fourthImg").click(function(){
        $('<p>Pratibha Devisingh Patil is an Indian politician who served as the 12th President of India from 2007 to 2012.</p>').appendTo('#content');
        $('#content').show();
    });
    $("#fifthImg").click(function(){
        $('<p>.Pranab Kumar Mukherjee  is the 13th and current President of India.</p>').appendTo('#content');
        $('#content').show();
    });
});
</script>

<style>

#contentBox{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    border:2px solid black;
    margin-top:10%;
}
</style>
```

hi i am trying to add content dynamically to div..here is my code..i have added 5 images.. if i click 1st image relevant text should be displayed in a content class.. same as for all images.. i wrote code for that...but data is not appending to div.. is there any mistake??

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: Specify what is not working and your html code to

Comment: data is not appending to that div

Comment: Do you also add your images dynamically

Comment: Maybe you gave the wrong ID. In the CSS you have `#contentBox`, but in the Javascript you have `#content`.

Comment: Show your HTML.

Comment: Your question says you want to add to the DIV, but the answer you accepted replaces the content instead of adding to it. Why did you accept that answer? If the question is written wrong, you should fix the question to say what you really want to do.

Comment: @Barmar .. ok..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove previously appended content every time on clicking the img. please check the below answer.

You can use this script also. Replace this with old one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#firstImg").click(function(){
      $('.content').html('<p>Shankar Dayal Sharma was the ninth President of India</p>');
    });
    $("#secondImg").click(function(){
      $('.content').html('<p>.Kocheril Raman Narayanan was the tenth President of India.<p>');
    });
    $("#thirdImg").click(function(){
        $('.content').html('<p>.Avul Pakir Jainulabdeen "A. P. J." Abdul Kalam  was the 11th President of India from 2002 to 2007.</p>');
    });
    $("#fourthImg").click(function(){
      $('.content').html('<p>Pratibha Devisingh Patil is an Indian politician who served as the 12th President of India from 2007 to 2012.</p>');
    });
    $("#fifthImg").click(function(){
      $('.content').html('<p>.Pranab Kumar Mukherjee  is the 13th and current President of India.</p>');
    });
});
```

or

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#firstImg").click(function(){
      $('.content').html('<p>Shankar Dayal Sharma was the ninth President of India</p>');
    });
    $("#secondImg").click(function(){
      $('.content').html('<p>.Kocheril Raman Narayanan was the tenth President of India.<p>');
    });
    $("#thirdImg").click(function(){
        $('.content').html('<p>.Avul Pakir Jainulabdeen "A. P. J." Abdul Kalam  was the 11th President of India from 2002 to 2007.</p>');
    });
    $("#fourthImg").click(function(){
      $('.content').html('<p>Pratibha Devisingh Patil is an Indian politician who served as the 12th President of India from 2007 to 2012.</p>');
    });
    $("#fifthImg").click(function(){
      $('.content').html('<p>.Pranab Kumar Mukherjee  is the 13th and current President of India.</p>');
    });
});
```

```css
.contentBox{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    border:2px solid black;
    margin-top:10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content"></div>

<img src="" alt="first image" id="firstImg">
<img src="" alt="second image" id="secondImg">
<img src="" alt="third image" id="thirdImg">
<img src="" alt="fourth image" id="fourthImg">
<img src="" alt="fifth image" id="fifthImg">
```

Comment: can i add tick-mark for visited images and cross-mark for unvisited images.. when i click submit i should appear.. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

.appendTo() will append the element. All your text will appear one after another.

$('#content').html('..your html..') may help you, if you just want to display the text of which image is clicked.

Is that what you want.

-- UPDATE --

If you just need to alter text on content div on click of every image, may be the following will be better.

```
<div id="content"></div>

<img src="" class="img" alt="image 1" data-text="text on image 1" />
<img src="" class="img" alt="image 2" data-text="text on image 2" />
.
.
.
<img src="" class="img" alt="image n" data-text="text on image n" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.img').on('click', function(){
    $('#content').html($(this).data('text'));
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate data id dynamically for both the img and p tag

```js
$('img').each(function(n){
  $(this).attr('data-id',n);
}); //dynamically generating data attr
$('p').each(function(n){
  $(this).attr('data-id',n);
}); //dynamically generating data attr
$('p').hide();
$('img').on('click',function(){
    $('p').hide();
    $('p[data-id="'+$(this).data('id')+'"]').show();    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content"></div>

<img src="" alt="first image" >
<img src="" alt="second image">
<img src="" alt="third image" >
<img src="" alt="fourth image">
<img src="" alt="fifth image" >
<p>Content for Image 1</p>
<p>Content for Image 2</p>
<p>Content for Image 3</p>
<p>Content for Image 4</p>
<p>Content for Image 5</p>
```